# PHP - base64_decode GET FILE INFORMATION

Tags: php, base64, decode

I have my Android Client - which send the binary base64 to the PHP server (Image - JPG/JPEG).

And here is my PHP server code to save the picture and decode the binary.

Now I want to check more about the file, so the FileSize, FileType but I found no possible function. I tried mime type but I couldn't make it.

Does anyone have an example for me?

```
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];

$binary=base64_decode($base);

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);

echo 'true';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$desc_array = stat('uploaded_image.jpg');
```

to get more information like

```
$desc_array["size"];
```

see http://php.net/manual/de/function.stat.php

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast reply. So I have to start the $desc_array after I have saved the picture ? Because I think its little bit more secure if I can check that before the image its saved